# Error in plotting function of atand against different values of angle

Tags: matlab, math

I am getting error Error using atand Argument should be real while executing below code. Kindly help to correct it.

```
n1=1.51; 
n2=1; 
anglec = asind (n2/n1); 
angleTE=[]; 
angleTM=[]; 
for angle= 42:1:90 
   angleTE(angle)= 2*atand((sqrt (((sind (angle))^2) - ((sind (anglec))^2))) / (cosd          (angle))); 
   angleTM(angle) = 2*atand( (sqrt (((sind(angle))^2) - ((sind (anglec))^2))) / ((cosd (angle))*(sind(anglec))^2)); 
end 

plot(angle,angleTE) 
plot(angle,angleTM)enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The trigonometric functions you are using then have a `d` suffix take degrees as an input, as you are doing, so that was not your problem here.  It was simply the the differences (e.g. `sind(angle)^2 - sind(anglec)^2`) that were giving you negative numbers to `sqrt`.  I see you have corrected that by changing the range of `angle` in the loop.

In that correction, your indexing of `angleTE` and `angleME` broke since they no longer start at `1`.  To do the indexing properly you will want to use a different loop variable.

Another problem you appear to be having now is just the plot commands.  The problem is that at the end of the loop, `angle` is just the last value it took (i.e. `90`).  So your plots are incorrect.  Since you are trying to do `plot(42:90, angleTE)` and `plot(42:90, angleTM)`, the fixes would be,

```
angle = 42:1:90;
for ii = 1:numel(angle),
    angleTE(ii) = 2*atand(sqrt(sind(angle(ii))^2 - sind(anglec)^2) / cosd(angle(ii))); 
    angleTM(ii) = 2*atand(sqrt(sind(angle(ii))^2 - sind(anglec)^2) / cosd(angle(ii))*sind(anglec)^2); 
end
```

Or put `angle = 42:1:90;` after your loop and deal with a bunch of zeros at the beginning of `angleTE` and `angleTM`, but that seems inelegant.

Finally, I would suggest preallocating `angleTE` and `angleTM` before the loop via,

```
angleTE = zeros(numel(angle),1);
angleTM = zeros(numel(angle),1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are taking sqrt of a negative number.

sqrt (((sind (1))^2) - ((sind (anglec))^2))

ans =

```
              0 + 0.662021652888396i
```

This is happening because you are using degrees, but Matlab is expecting radians.

Comment: I have made changes to remove complex numbers. Can you suggest something more about radians and degrees in form of code. Thanks

Comment: Why in the world would somebody vote down this answer?  It answers the question, and identifies the main problem, sqrt of a negative number.  Coming from a Fortran and science background, it never occurred to me that sind was "sin, using degrees."  I assumed it was "sin, double precision."  OK, my bad.  So, correct me, or edit my comment.  Too many people here are downvote-happy.  It discourages newcomers like me.